# Input strings must be a multiple of 16 in length Python pycrypto

Tags: python, python-3.x, aes, pycrypto

I'm trying to get into cryptography with python and got a question. Here is some code i did for learning and testing.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import getpass
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import hashlib
import random
import sys
import os

the_input = getpass.getpass("Enter password: ")
theHash = hashlib.sha256(the_input.encode("utf-8")).hexdigest()

key = theHash[0:16]
#IV = ''.join([chr(random.randint(0, 0xff)) for i in range(16)])
IV = os.urandom(16)
print("THEHASH: ", key, "Leangth: ", len(key))
print( "IVlen: ", len(IV), "|SYS,GETSIZEOF: ", sys.getsizeof(IV))
print("This is the IV: ", IV)
def Encrypt_str():
    aes1 = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, IV)
    data = 'whatevertest'.zfill(16)

    encr = aes1.encrypt(data)
    print("The ENCRYPTION: ",encr)
    aes2 = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, IV)
    decr = aes2.decrypt(encr)
    print("Decrypted: ", decr)

def Decrypt_str():
    aes2 = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, IV)
    inpa1 = input("Enter cip:")
    decr = aes2.decrypt(inpa1)
    print(decr)

Encrypt_str()
Decrypt_str()
```

On the line

```
print("The ENCRYPTION: ",encr)
```

it prints the encrypted code with .zfill(16) bytes

that code is b'\x0c\x97\x8e\x1b\xa9\x10a\n\x07\xde\x16\xa3\xf7\x10\x9f5'

when i'm running

```
len('\x0c\x97\x8e\x1b\xa9\x10a\n\x07\xde\x16\xa3\xf7\x10\x9f5') in interpreter
```

i am getting 16 in return and when i paste the encrypted aes code in

```
inpa1 = input("Enter cip:")
```

i'm getting

```
File "newtest.py", line 35, in <module>
    Decrypt_str()
  File "newtest.py", line 31, in Decrypt_str
    decr = aes2.decrypt(inpa1)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/Crypto/Cipher/blockalgo.py", line 295, i$
    return self._cipher.decrypt(ciphertext)
ValueError: Input strings must be a multiple of 16 in length
```

But still i can decrypt the same 16 bytes in same function with

```
decr = aes2.decrypt(encr)
```

Which i find weird...so i can't really get how this is working. some help would be appriciated.

Comment: `input()` doesn’t convert those backslash escape codes into bytes. Use base-64 encoding or something.

Answer (score 0):

If you are pasting `\x0c\x97\x8e\x1b\xa9\x10a\n\x07\xde\x16\xa3\xf7\x10\x9f5` directly into the input prompt, the backslashes are being escaped.

```
>>> example=input("Prompt: ")
Prompt: \x0c\x97\x8e\x1b\xa9\x10a\n\x07\xde\x16\xa3\xf7\x10\x9f5
>>> example
'\\x0c\\x97\\x8e\\x1b\\xa9\\x10a\\n\\x07\\xde\\x16\\xa3\\xf7\\x10\\x9f5'
>>> print(example)
\x0c\x97\x8e\x1b\xa9\x10a\n\x07\xde\x16\xa3\xf7\x10\x9f5
```

Generally when communicating encrypted values it is good practice to base64 encode the values.  Then decode the values before decrypting the value.

```
>>> import base64
>>> enc=b'\x0c\x97\x8e\x1b\xa9\x10a\n\x07\xde\x16\xa3\xf7\x10\x9f5'
>>> base64_enc = base64.b64encode(enc)
>>> print(base64_enc)
b'DJeOG6kQYQoH3haj9xCfNQ=='
>>>
>>> i=input("Prompt: ")
Prompt: DJeOG6kQYQoH3haj9xCfNQ==
>>>
>>> i
'DJeOG6kQYQoH3haj9xCfNQ=='
>>> denc=base64.b64decode(i)
>>> print(denc)
b'\x0c\x97\x8e\x1b\xa9\x10a\n\x07\xde\x16\xa3\xf7\x10\x9f5'
>>> len(denc)
16
```

Comment: okay thanks guys i got this now its working using bas64 as input!

Comment: Seems like i can't vote with a reputation lower then 15 here on stack overflow